# Forum Requires Manual Entry of User name & Email for Authenticated User?

Tags: kentico, kentico-12

Is there a setting somewhere to use the authenticated user information instead of forcing user entry, or do I have to go through the process of creating a custom forum layout to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom layout, you can simply modify the out of the box one.